# Browser not secure, using user:pass@ip:port proxies on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, security, proxy

To the left of the web address search bar, it says not secure. How can I fix this?

I'm just wondering if this is fixable as I can't find anything online about it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That refers to the page being accessed by http or https which is a server setting.

Comment: @DMart how can I just use https then, I assume it is defaulting to http. Https and http proxy are both the same, how can I select which one to use.